# Equidistant printing in python

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
for k in sorted(data):
    print '%s:\t\t%s' % (k, data[k])
```

Which prints for me:

```
Date:       2016-03-05
NumMovieTerritories:        164
NumMovieTerritoriesLive:        111
NumMovieTitles:     115393
NumMovieTitlesLive:     103785
NumProviders:       1411
NumProvidersLive:       1136
NumTVTerritories:       36
NumTVTerritoriesLive:       6
NumTVTitles:        424321
NumTVTitlesLive:        392832
NumTerritoryAvails:     1837294
NumTerritoryAvailsLive:     1597407
```

How would I do it such that it prints like a table of contents:

```
Date:                       2016-03-05
NumMovieTerritories:        164
NumMovieTerritoriesLive:    111
NumMovieTitles:             115393
NumMovieTitlesLive:         103785
NumProviders:               1411
NumProvidersLive:           1136
NumTVTerritories:           36
NumTVTerritoriesLive:       6
NumTVTitles:                424321
NumTVTitlesLive:            392832
NumTerritoryAvails:         1837294
NumTerritoryAvailsLive:     1597407
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You first need to know how wide you want your text.  To do that, you need to find the max length in the dictionary.  We can do that with `max_length = max(len(k) for k in data)`.  Next, we can use `str.ljust()` to put the string in that field.  This is the final result:

```
max_length = max(len(k) for k in data)
for k in sorted(data):
    print("{}:  {}".format(k.ljust(max_length), data[k]))
```

Comment: Can get the exact format if the last line changes to `print("{}:{}    {}".format(k, ' ' * (max_length - len(k)), data[k]))` Cool to learn about `ljust()` though!